# Probability of Winning with 2 Goals or More

Tags: probability, statistics

I have some data on a game I'm playing and I'm trying to interpret my results.

Let's say I have a soccer team. Whenever that soccer team had scored 5 goals, they won 100% of their games. Whenever they had scored 4 goals, they also won 100% of their games. 3 goals won 80% of games. 2 goals won 78% of games. 1 goal won 30% of games. Let's also say that you can only score a maximum of 5 goals in a game.

What is the probability of winning a game when they score 2 or more goals?

Thinking about it further, you may also need the number of games where the team gets x goals:

| Goals | Number of Games | Number of Wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 | 10 |
| 4 | 13 | 13 |
| 3 | 15 | 12 |
| 2 | 14 | 11 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 0 | 16 | 0 |

**Attempts at a solution:**

There are 2 probabilities at work here: the probability of scoring x goals and the probability of winning with x goals.

Take the total games won with 2+ goals / total games played with 2+ goals
= (0.78 * 14 + 0.8 * 15 + 13 + 10)/(14+15+13+10)
= 88%

Is this correct?

Comment: I haven't done the arithmetic, but I think so.  My analysis would be that of the $52$ games in which the team scored at least $2$ goals, it won $46$ of them, so the probability of a win, given that the team scored at least $2$ goals, is $\frac{46}{52} \approx 0.885$.

Comment: You ask about a probability without introducing any random elements. All we have are data about past games. If you ask for a probability, you need to state the probabilistic model that you want to apply. The only model I can think of that you may have intended to imply is that we uniformly randomly choose a game from among the listed past games. But it’s far from obvious that that’s what you mean; you’d need to state it.